# If I know the freezing point of two solutions, and combine them into one solution, what is the resulting freezing point?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am not knowledgeable in chemistry in any way, so I'm sorry if I seem stupid or something.

Suppose I have two solutions which I know the freezing point of, and I combine them into one solution. How do I find the resulting freezing point?

For example, let's say I have 4 parts water and 1 part maple syrup. Freezing point of water is $0 \ ^oC$, and freezing point of maple syrup is about $ -13\ ^oC$ according to a page I found from a google search.

Intuition tells me it would just be a weighted average of all the things you're combining, assuming that there is no chemical reaction when you mix them. So for my water plus maple example, it would be
$$
\left( \frac{4}{(4 + 1)}  * 0 \right)+ \left( \frac{1}{(4 + 1)} * -13 \right) = \frac{-13}{5} = -2.6 \ ^oC
$$.

Is this intuition correct or is it more complex than that?

Comment: It is more complex.  For volume ratios, it would have to be corrected by densities. Even then, freezing point as function of composition is not linear. So, it can be used only as rough estimation that would differ from reality.

Comment: Okay suppose I measure the parts by mass instead of volume. If the function of freezing point isn't linear, what is it?

Comment: Nonlinear, empirical function. It is approximately linear for very diluted solutions, what is not case of syrups.

Comment: The dream of many physical chemists would be to describe the properties of a mixture by the properties of the individual components. Unfortunately, thermodynamics of solutions is much more complex and you can't use simple rules like that. However, if you have some properties and data, we could see that the solid/liquid equilibrium tells us and get a rough estimation.

Comment: You need to clarify whether your question is about maple syrup specifically or mixtures generally.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, the freezing point of a mixture is *lower* than the freezing point of each component.

For example, table salt, $\ce{NaCl}$, melts at ~800°C. Water, $\ce{H2O}$, melts at 0°C. A mixture of salt and water can have a [melting point as low as -20°C!](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/sodium-chloride-water-d_1187.html). This is called [freezing point depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing-point_depression).

Another example is the melting point of mixed metals, i.e., an alloy. Tin, Sn and lead, Pb, are used to make classic solder. The melting point of Sn is ~230°C, and of Pb, ~330°C, [but a 60% Sn/40% Pb alloy melts about 180°C.](https://byjus.com/chemistry/eutectic-point/)

It is difficult to make a general statement about the melting point of mixtures. In some case, there might not be a freezing point depression, but in most, the freezing point does *not* vary linearly with concentration.

Don't despair though -- there *are* properties of sugar/water solutions that *do* vary *comparatively* linearly with concentration, such as the density and [index of refraction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346635/refractive-index-as-a-function-of-concentration-of-sugar-solution-and-wavelength). Those making alcohol from sugary solutions may use refractometers to check the amount of sugar. *Cheers! Salud! L'chaim! Skol!*

Comment: Dr Moishe Pippik states about melting points of mixtures. It has nothing to do with Logan Schlick's question.

Comment: @Maurice, it certainly *does* have to do with the question: interpolation of freezing point data: "Suppose I have two solutions which I know the freezing point of, and I combine them into one solution. How do I find the resulting freezing point?" If equal amounts of solutions of 20% ethylene glycol/80% H2O and 80% ethylene glycol/20 % water are mixed, the f.p. is **not** halfway between. https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/738-figure-732-shows-phase-diagram-h2o-ethylene-glycol-explain-mixture-approximately-50-50-q37847872